# JavaScript getting strange error when using " ' " + var

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use the following line in the console (FF & chrome)

```
var stripID = "\'#strip_" + ID + "\'";
console.log(stripID);
```

I get what I wanted: `'#strip_126327'`
But when I put it in the JS file, and the function executing this, is triggered i get

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''
```

withut even a file and line reference.

Also, the purpose of all this is to get a string to put in `$()` selector.

Comment: Why are you escaping the single quotes? Did you try this: `var stripID = "'#strip_" + ID + "'";`

Comment: If your purpose is get it into `$`, then you don't need those `'` at all.

Comment: All the answers below are correct.  Just keep in mind that selectors require a string variable, it doesn't care how you build that string variable.  You can use ' or ", it doesn't matter.  Just give it a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes in there:

```
var stripID = "#strip_" + ID;
$(stripID).whatever();
```

is sufficient. `'` is not a valid character in a selector.

Comment: @Marc B the weird thing is that when i use it like that the selector doesn't work! i get `undefined`, and when I run it in the console, with `'` it works... any ideas why?

Comment: There's a difference between `$(#strip_XX)` and `$('#strip_XX')`. The first one is an illegal bare string. The other one is a string that corresponds to a selector. `var x = '#strip_XX'; $(x)` is legal.

Comment: @IlyaD in javascript you define a string with `var foo = "foo_bar"` Now you have a variable that holds `"foo_bar"` as a value. It doesn't contain `"'foo_bar'"`. I think this is where you are confused. I hope this helps. Marc's answer is 100% right here. Sharing more code can also help us tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to escape `'` because you are already using `"`. But even more importantly, you don't even need `'`.  Just do `var stripID = "#strip_" + ID;`

As other have said, `'#id_foo'` is actually not a valid jquery selector. You want a string that has the value of `#id_foo`. Read more on selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a jQuery selector that looks like `'#srip_something'`.

That is not a valid jQuery selector, so jQuery throws this error.
jQuery selectors are ordinary strings and only contain quotes within the strings for attribute values.